# Как отправить файл большого размера через телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите, каким образом можно отправить файл большого размера через бота? Файлы в среднем больше 100мб, пытался через request и через await bot.send_document
В двух вариантах выдаёт ошибку, что файл слишком большой.

```
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.token}/sendDocument?chat_id={iduser}'
                filepath = r'C:\Users\nevajno\Desktop\Bot\filename.zip'
                r = requests.post(url, files={"document": open(filepath, 'rb')})
                print(r.status_code)
                print(r.text)


await bot.send_document(iduser, open(f'{login}.zip', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Таким образом вы можете отправить файл не больше 50мб https://ramziv.com/blog/19., ограничении нет только на файлы которые уже есть на сервере телеграм, то есть если отравлять уже загруженный файл через `file_id`. Как вариант разбить архив с файлами по 50 мб, и отправлять по очереди.

Comment: Как вариант - заливайте в гуглодиск/дропбокс/etc и отправляйте в телегу ссчылку если файл больше разрешенного размера.

Comment: @Sheridan Сделал залив на дропбокс, но во время загрузки бот просто не реагирует на другие команды.

Возможно ли как-то это исправить? Сделать этот залив асинхронным?

`dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(config.dropboxtoken)
with open(f'{file_path}', 'rb') as file:
    response = dbx.files_upload(file.read(), f'/{filename}')
url = dbx.files_get_temporary_link(f'/{filename}').link`

Comment: Ну так то да, в отдельном потоке делай...